# Anyway to stop SharePoint 2013 Quick Launch adding items automatically

Tags: 2013, quick-launch

In SharePoint 2013, Lists and Subsites are added to the Quick Launch automatically. Is there anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lists**

When you create a List it has an option whether to show that list in Quick Launch or not, you can uncheck the checkbox, as shown below:

[image: List on Quick Launch]

If you are making the list via code, you have `SPList.OnQuickLaunch` property, which you can set to false!

**Subsites**

You can activate Publishing feature for your Site and once your Web is Publishing.. In Site Settings -> Under Look and Feel -> Navigation. There you can handle whether or not to show subsites and pages under Quick Launch/Top Navigation (Current Navigation)

[image: Example]

PS: [Configure the Quick Launch for site navigation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/configure-the-quick-launch-for-site-navigation-HA102130960.aspx)